# how build dynamic layout mvc 4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

how return razor code  for layout of view instead of master page name 
  for example instead of

```
return View("Index", "_Layout");
```

use this code

```
 return View("Index", @"

@using System.Diagnostics
@using iaumahallat.Helper
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>@ViewBag.SiteTitle - @ViewBag.Title</title>
    <meta name="description" content="@ViewBag.MetaDescription">

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

</head>
<body>

           @RenderBody()

  @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)



</body>
</html>


");
```

Comment: You can't, because that isn't a valid string literal ;)

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use [RazorEngine](http://razorengine.codeplex.com/) and parse the razor source code, then get the corresponding Html String to display it on the view or layout-

```
 Razor.SetTemplateBase(typeof(HtmlTemplateBase<>));

  string template = 
  @"<html>
      <head>
        <title>Hello @Model.Name</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        Email: @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email)
      </body>
    </html>";

  var model = new PageModel { Name = "World", Email = "someone@somewhere.com" };
  string result = Razor.Parse(template, model);
```

Then use `result` in the page of your interest.